# How to use a button on a User Form to clear contents of content control boxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am need to clear information from a content control box and not delete the content control box itself when i press clear button on user form.

I am unable to link my code (below) to the clear button on user form to be able test....

```
Private Sub DeleteCCByTag_Alternative(ccTag As String)    
    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag(ccTag).Item(1)

    With cc

        .LockContentControl = False
        .LockContents = False

        .Range.Delete               'to delete CC content

        .Delete (False)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this code work ?

Comment: @Walter-moolman: Please tell us what is wrong with the code you have

Comment: I am unable to link it to the clear button on user form to be able test.... I know a little bit of coding but struggle with this

Comment: @WalterMoolman Whats the name of your button ? ( Properties then check name row)

Comment: Walter, double-click the button on the User Form in its "design mode". That will generate a click event for the button. Then you can add your code, or call the procedure you have from within the "click" procedure.